# Ledger Nano S hardware wallet instructions for using Monero?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Are details provided at https://github.com/LedgerHQ/blue-app-monero/blob/master/doc/user/bolos-app-monero.pdf and https://github.com/LedgerHQ/blue-app-monero/blob/master/doc/user/bolos-app-monero.rst sufficient for a hacker to get a Nano S to function with a working version 0.12.0.0 of **monero-wallet-cli**?

Does anyone find the details located in Section 3.2 of the PDF to be exceptionally pedantic for the hosting OS that Ledger hardware wallet connects to?

Comment: It is unclear if [**Section 3.2.2**](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/blue-app-monero/blob/master/doc/user/bolos-app-monero.pdf) for the Mac is to install a SmartCard device driver for the ledger and if the path for **--generate-from-device** (per Section 5.1.1) is really the path for the Ledger SmartCard device driver. For the Mac, it might be nice if there were Homebrew package for installing the https://github.com/smartcardservices package as a bottle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a Ledger Monero wallet with the CLI (monero-wallet-cli)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-cli-monero-wallet-cli) ?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/ledger-nano-s-hardware-wallet-instructions-for-using-monero?noredirect=1#comment7770_7986 answers the question for OSX. Monero v0.12.2.0 should be used.