# Buying Monero and saving to Ledger

Tags: transactions

I wish to buy cryptocurrency (Monero) for the first time: I have no real knowledge of how to do this, and I wish to pay in cash. Can this be done? I have bought a Ledger Nano S but haven't received it yet. Could someone spell out step by step how I do this without getting ripped off? Is Monero a good choice for investment?

Answer (score 6):

You can purchase Monero for cash directly on sites like https://localmonero.co/. Alternatively buy BTC for cash somewhere like https://localbitcoins.com/ and convert to BTC to XMR on something like Bisq or ShapeShift.

You specifically stated "pay in cash" which is why I didn't list alternatives.

To store on a Ledger, you will need to set this up first (either using the Monero GUI or CLI) and use your new wallet address as your receiving wallet when you buy your XMR. A GUI guide can be found [here](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006352934-Monero-XMR-Advanced-users) and CLI [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/8504/7493).

Answer (score 1):

Your subsidiary question is *“Is Monero a good choice for investment?”*, and you are presumably using “investment” to mean either “trading” or “speculation”. Monero, like $, ¥, £, ฿, €, ₦ *etc.* doesn't produce goods or services so the word “investment” doesn't apply. I will therefore comment on trading and speculation.

Monero is newer than $, ¥, £, ฿, €,₦ *etc.*, so its exchange rates are more volatile, and a skilled trader can make money out of exchange rate volatility. At its simplest this means buying at the troughs and selling at the peaks, while more sophisticated trading techniques (*e.g.* [short selling](https://www.investopedia.com/university/shortselling/shortselling1.asp)) are used to profit while prices are falling. However, very few people have the skill and self-discipline to profit from trading in the long run. Bad short selling strategies can be ruinously expensive.

If you meant “speculation”, then you're effectively asking *“Will Monero be worth more at some point in the future than it's worth now?”* If you had asked that question in 2016, and your “point in the future” was *now* (Aug 2018), then the answer would have been *Yes*. But if you had asked the same question in Jan 2018, then the answer would have been *No*. In either case, the answer would have been determined more by market irrationality than by fundamentals. A simplistic fundamental analysis says Monero *should* be worth more now than it was in the past because more man-hours have gone into improving the technology (of both the currency itself and its supporting infrastructure). Monero's purpose is safe, decentralized and fungible value-transfer, so if you speculate that its value will go up, you're really speculating *(i)* that there's a growing demand for safe, decentralized and fungible value-transfer and *(ii)* that Monero (rather than some alternative project) will prove to be the best technology for this purpose. One disadvantage of using Monero for speculation is that there are no derivatives available to hedge your position.

Comment: Your reply is appreciated. I have $10K available.  I know as much about business, stocks, bonds, as I do about crypto anything. I was considering buying 2 Antminer A7s, (as I have access to free electricity on that scale) but am too unsure as to the feasibility of such a venture. Reading about Monero  and ASICs and so one, it occurred to me that this currency may very well become attractive to many people in the foreseeable future (2 to 5 years). Look what happened to Bitcoin... So my question I wonder if my rationale appears to sound to those who are in the know about crypto everything.

Comment: I personally do believe that there's a growing demand for safe, decentralized and fungible value-transfer; and that this will grow as the public become more aware of the personal data security scandals that we hear about in the news. Monero looks like the front-runner *at the moment*, but the risk for a speculator is that someone invents a *better* alternative. For instance, it's said that Grin (not live yet) will have a smaller blockchain. Fungibility is *very* interesting for speculators: the possibility that bitcoin holders will one day panic *en mass* about retrospective analyses of coins.