# Removing private view key from computer after exporting from ledger?

Tags: privacy, viewkey, ledger

According to [How do I generate a Ledger Monero wallet with the CLI (monero-wallet-cli)?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-cli-monero-wallet-cli/8504?newreg=4aa3e148c47e465d91eaee97d1b35c7d) exporting the private view key when generating or using the monero wallet with a ledger device speeds up block scanning, but at the same time:

> if your system gets compromised, the adversary will potentially be able to compromise your private view key as well, which is detrimental to privacy

Is the private view key removed from the computer once the wallet application is closed? If not, can it be manually removed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually remove the wallet files from your computer. The best option would be to store them on an encrypted removable device.