# My Ledger Monero wallet shows an incoming transaction with a value of zero (0), how do I resolve this issue?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, ledger, transfer

I withdrew some funds from an exchange to my Ledger Monero wallet. However, the incoming has a value of zero (0). How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. Transaction shows in monero gui wallet, but the balance is 0. None of the above was helpful. Any ideas? next transaction was successful and funds are shown.

Comment: Can you try recreating the Ledger Monero wallet? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is caused by the GUI wallet, if used in conjunction with Ledger Monero App v1.1.3 (or lower), not being able to properly decode the amount. Fortunately, however, the following fix can be used to resolve your issue:

**In case you are using the GUI:**

1. Exit the GUI (make sure you are using GUI v0.14.1.0).
2. Make sure your Ledger Monero app is upgraded to v1.3.1
3. Make sure your Ledger Live firmware is upgraded to v1.6.0
4. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).
5. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`
6. Restart the GUI. This will trigger a wallet refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.

---

**In case you are using the CLI:**

1. Exit `monero-wallet-cli` (make sure you are using CLI v0.14.1.0).
2. Make sure your Ledger Monero app is upgraded to v1.3.1
3. Make sure your Ledger Live firmware is upgraded to v1.6.0
4. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (normally in the same folder as `monero-wallet-cli`)
5. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`
6. Restart `monero-wallet-cli`. This will trigger a wallet refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.