# Transaction not received on ledger s nano

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I sent XMR from Kraken to my GUI primary address on ledger s nano about 24 hours ago, but I still haven't received anything. Daemon is synchronized and wallet is synchronized. Status is success on Kraken.

When I go to "History" it says "Received 0 XMR" under the correct time and date of my transaction.

What to do?

Comment: I am running GUI version 0.14.0.0 and embedded Monero Version 0.14.0.2 as well as Ledger Live 1.8.0.

Comment: I have started completing the steps said here, I will update how it goes in this tread https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You should be able to resolve your issue with the guide I linked: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/my-ledger-monero-wallet-shows-an-incoming-transaction-with-a-value-of-zero-0