# Ledger Monero wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

What is the long address I see on my Ledger Nano S when I open in the Monero app?

Are the 24 seed words for the Ledger BTC wallet also needed to restore the Monero wallet? Because in Monero, the restore wallet option is asking for 25 words. I'm a little confused.

Thanks to everyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your 24 word seed is your *Ledger device* seed which is used for restoring the Ledger. It is used in the Ledger Live app when you need to [restore a device](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005434914). Recall that the Ledger has your wallet private keys, not the Monero GUI application. Each Ledger device only uses one seed phrase; you do not have different seeds for each cryptocurrency you use your Ledger for.

Ledger has a [full guide](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006352934-Monero-XMR-) for using Monero with your Ledger and there is also a [guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/9902/7493) on StackExchange. There is also [this guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10599/7493) for restoring a Ledger with Monero.

The long address you mention I can only assume is your wallet address, though I don't have a Ledger to confirm this.

Comment: I noticed the Ledger Nano S Monero app produces an address before I have entered any kind of passphrase. Does this mean the Monero app does not use the "passphrase as a 25th seed word" scheme?