# Rescan Ledger wallet from 0 in the GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I created a fresh Ledger wallet using the 0.14.1.0 GUI on Windows 10. That's working fine as expected.

I tried to force the GUI to rescan the Ledger account from block 0 by renaming the wallet cache file. But when I do that, the GUI opens the .keys file and only scans the blockchain from roughly 20,000 blocks in the past. Is there some info in the keys file that is indicating the creation date of the wallet?

On a side note, attempting to force a rescan using the GUI results in this error:

```
rescan spent can only be used with a trusted daemon
```

I have seen that this function of the GUI may not be wired-up yet. However, my remote node is run by me and the tickbox for trusting it is marked. I have tried un-ticking and re-ticking, but it did not help.

Comment: The wallet creation height is embedded in the `.keys` file. Thus, renaming the wallet cache file will result in a rescan from scratch with the same wallet creation height (which for new wallets is approximately 20k blocks lower than the current height). Note that you can also trigger a wallet rescan by changing the wallet creation height on the `Settings` page.

Comment: re: trusted daemon, have you tried ticking the box and subsequently restarting the GUI?

Comment: If the wallet creation height is emedded in the keys file, doesn't this pose a problem if 5 years into the future I lose both my Ledger and original .keys file? When I restore the Ledger with the seed words and create a new wallet .keys file in the Monero client, how will it know that it needs to start scanning the chain from 5+ years ago? This is my main reason for asking about scanning from 0.

Comment: Attempting to rescan from the Settings -> Wallet tab again still results in the error in my initial question, even after restarting the GUI. If it's worth noting, my remote node requires a username and password. Changing the wallet restore height in Settings -> Info did indeed cause the GUI to rescan from a lower block height. Thanks.

Comment: 1. No, because you can easily regenerate the .keys file with a proper restore height.See -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet | 2. You need to supply it with a proper restore height. You can consult the table in the link I added.

Comment: "Wallet tab again still results in the error in my initial question" <= What does this mean exactly? Is the trusted mode not working properly or?

Comment: Marking my remote node as "trusted" in the GUI is not enabling me to rescan the chain using the ```rescan``` button. In my case, the trusted tickbox is not working properly.

Comment: Apparently there is a bug with the rescan button. See: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/pull/2329 | A work around that can be used currently is to simply change the `Wallet creation height` on the `Settings` page, which will trigger a wallet refresh.

Answer (score 2):

With the wallet open, changing the wallet restore height in the GUI's `Settings` section under the `Info` tab will cause the chain to be re-scanned from the block height specified.