# Funds not showing in GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I recently installed the Monero GUI wallet and connected it to my Ledger Nano S.
I then transferred my Monero from Binance to my GUI wallet address and received a successful Transaction ID From Binance and see it in block 2270830.

However, my coins are not showing in the wallet.

Because I am using my Ledger, I cannot access my Secret View Key, so using block explorers to see more detail is not an option.

My wallet info is:

```
GUI version: 0.17.1.9-3ca5f10f (Qt 5.15.2)
Embedded Monero version: 0.17.1.9-release
Wallet restore height: 2271489
Wallet mode: Advanced mode (Local node)OpenGL
```

My Local Node shows as synchronized:

```
2021-01-10 14:53:29.895 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-01-10 14:53:38.162 I Synced 2271497/2271497
2021-01-10 14:53:38.163 I SYNCHRONIZED OK
```

My funds seem to be in limbo.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Your wallet restore height (2271489) is *above* the height of your transaction (2270830). You therefore need to change the restore height to force a rescan from *before* the height the transaction occurred. See [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11513/7493).

Comment: Thank you for the reply jtgrassie After many trials and errors, i finally managed to edit the Wallet Restore Height and complete a rebuild of the cache One of the issues with the Ledger device is, the longest it will stay connected is 10 minutes
These wallet changes require 30 - 60 minutes or longer at times Once the Ledger locks, it seems the wallet stops updating Trying to open the Ledger and reconnect causes more issues and the wallet GUI seems to get hung up. In every case the ledger locks and stops synchronizing the wallet, i had to close the wallet, change the Wallet Height manually agai

Comment: @Capblye - Did you export the private view key on the Ledger device?

Comment: dEBRUYNE - yes, it prompts you on the ledger everytime to push the button to export the private view key
However, it always shows up as a string of 000000's in the Wallet