# Transferred Monero to a ledger nano x and everything worked fine. then connect to GUI and accept wallet key it says doesn't match

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Purchased new Ledger X and added cryptos to it. Found out after I need special Monero GUI to use Monero with Ledger. Also another crypto Stellar uses browser to access funds.
I go to access Monero through the GUI and is has trouble loading and i hit accept key and it says key does not match. At some point I had reinstalled the program or updated it and think that might be the problem. The password I used doesn't work! I saved the seed and thought I placed the pend key with the seed but it is not there... I have the public key and the view key so I end up using the seed and find out I need to convert the seed ! that does not work as final step I get a permission denied.
Now I see something about inputting height to reset the wallet but not sure how that works. I created in on the 9th or 10th of April 2020. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Have you followed https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10599/7493 yet?

Comment: As stated on Reddit, you do not need to convert the seed in order to utilize a Ledger Monero wallet. You can simply use the guide @jtgrassie linked (in case you haven't sent funds to the Ledger Monero address yet, you can use this guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui).