# I'm using GUI version 0.15.0.1 and was trying to send XMR to an exchange using Ledger Nano S

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

First I got the Error: Can't create transaction: unexpected error: Wrong Device Status: SW=1 ((EXPECT=9000, MASK=ffff). Then, as I re inputted the Ledger Nano S PIN and tried again I got the normal message: Creating Transaction Please check your hardware wallet - your input may be required. This message ran for ages (about an hour) and I put the PIN into the Ledger nano S again. This time I got the various messages: Accept Fee, Verify Amount and Destination, Accept TX and OK these.The amount of XMR remained the same and I thought I would wait so closed the wallet down.

On trying to log back in with password I get: Couldn't open Wallet: Wrong Device Status: SW=6e00 (Expect=9000,MASK=ffff).

Truly appreciate any help to be able to 1) access wallet and 2) SEND funds

Comment: Which version of the Ledger Monero App do you have? You can check on the device.

Comment: Hi dEBRUYNE, Thanks for reaching out. The Monero app version on the Ledger is 1.6.0

Comment: After the error messages above I updated the Ledger Live application. In this newer version (2.7.0) the apps automatically update through the manager. It may be possible that the Monero app was at a lower version than 1.6.0 at the time the above problems occured.

Comment: Please see my comments here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12296/problems-sending-from-gui-nitrogen-nebula-ledger-nano-s | It basically applies to your situation too.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had read that explanation earlier. However, I'm still on GUI version: v0.15.0.1 (Qt 5.9.7). The Monero app version on the Ledger is 1.6.0. I restored the main wallet which is fine but when trying to restore my hardware wallet I get the same Wrong Device Status:  SW=1 ((EXPECT=9000, MASK=ffff).  Question: should I wait for the new version or do I have a different problem? Perhaps I should upgrade from v 0.15.0.1 to 0.16.0.0 and see? Appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: The Ledger Monero App v1.6.0 can only be used with GUI v0.16.0.0, which contains the bug that inhibits people with a Ledger Monero wallet from sending transactions with multiple inputs. Probably easiest to wait until GUI v0.16.0.2 is released and then upgrade.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Wallets working OK since I upgraded to GUI v0.16.0.0 . Just have the bug when sending transactions with multiple inputs. I await the later version. Many thanks for helping me resolve the issue of not being able to open my wallet. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome and note that GUI v0.16.0.2 is now released! https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/hp6sly/gui_v01602_nitrogen_nebula_released/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been resolved in the comments.