# I cannot recreate/ open my ledger wallet, whats wrong?

Tags: wallet, hardware

i have already carried out your advise to the question , how do i restore/recreate my ledger wallet. but it still does not open? the message 'error writing wallet from hardware device. check application logs' comes up on wallet. how do i do this?
I have the original Ledger device i created the ledger wallet with and indeed transfered some monero into it.

what else can i do please?
thanks
stephen

Comment: You didn't happen to fall victim to the email phishing campaigns? Claiming a breech and to download new version?

Comment: No i dont think so, as i say i have been on the wallet and transfered a sample small amount of monero to it.

Comment: Make sure to update your GUI to v0.17.1.1, your Ledger firmware to v1.6.1, and your Ledger Monero App to v1.7.4. That should resolve the issue. Additionally, you can use this guide to recreate / restore your Ledger Monero wallet. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet/

Comment: plz update firmware your Leger
and download/install last monero wallet 0.17.1.1 *maybe you need seeds after update firmware your leger be careful