# Monero wallet doesn't update with latest tx

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, balance

On mac using Ledger.
With ledger Live 2.15.0 and Monero 1.7.4.
Monero wallet gui is 0.17.1.1-33afd0b (Qt 5.12.8)
I'm using a remote node.

My problem is I've made this [transaction](https://www.exploremonero.com/transaction/54183a25957dc5de820b8b11da4f314d94150a816d85ec2dcfa9fc438c5805e3) but it does not show in the wallet. Even after it fully synchronised. Clicking on Rescan wallet balance just freezes the app :(

How can I get my wallet's balance updated with the transaction i made 2 weeks ago?

Comment: Try recreating / restoring your Ledger Monero wallet. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet/

Comment: omg, when reading those guides I read what the `export private key` is. So i stopped restoring, and opened the old wallet and just selected to export it. I always denied the export. Now it is up to date. FML.

Comment: Going to mark this as solved then :)