# Monero wallet gui keeps quitting sporadically on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos

I'm new to Monero, and installed the Monero wallet GUI yesterday on my iMac running MacOS Catalina. The GUI version is 0.17.1.8-8e6a2cd (Qt 5.12.8) and is connected to my Ledger Nano S. The Monero wallet GUI app keeps quitting sporadically and I'm wondering if this is an issue with MacOS Catalina or if there is another reason?
I also tried transferring a small amount of Monero from Binance yesterday as a test case. Binance has recorded the transfer as being complete, but the tokens have not shown up on my Monero wallet GUI after 24 hours. From checking the transaction on the Blockchair Monero Explorer, it looks like the transaction has been confirmed even though it still isn't showing in my GUI wallet.
I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Did you export the private view key on the Ledger device?

Comment: I did as far as I know. The Ledger Nano S asks for confirmation to export the private view key on connecting it to the Monero wallet GUI, and I clicked yes. I made a mistake in my post - I'm running MacOS Big Sur, which is the latest Mac OS version.

Comment: Can you try to recreate your Ledger Monero wallet? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet/

Comment: I just recreated my Ledger Monero wallet, but it's still showing a 0 amount in the account. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Can you try connecting to a remote node? https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/krgdad/monero_gui_wallet_node_help/gijc85j/?context=3

Comment: Will give that a go.

Comment: I was about to try connecting to a remote node a short while ago, when the notification came up to update the GUI wallet app. I did the update and when I launched it, my tokens are now showing in the wallet. The transaction date is actually showing as 13 days ago, which is when I first sent the coins. So, I don't know if it's because of the update or whether it just needed more time. Thanks for all your help.