# Monero MAC GUI crashes when sending

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, view-only

After recently setting up Trezor T with the MAC Monero GUI, I went to send Monero on the Trezor T, and every time I tried it crashed the Monero GUI. After poking around.... In settings I noticed that (for some dumb reason) I made the Trezor T "view only". (I think this is why the Monero GUI crashes every time I try to send....

My question is what is the best/safest way to make the Trezor T "spendable"?

I have not tried anything yet for fear of losing stored assets on this "View Only" Trezor T.

Comment: Since the Monero GUI has a button in settings to make account view only, I would suggest they also add a button in settings that makes the account Spendable.

Comment: This is a bug. Whatever the Trezor's configuration, the Monero GUI should not crash. Can you give more information about that crash, such as a stack trace or similar ?

Comment: Now the situation is going from bad to worse.  Without doing anything.  No changes were made, except for passing time.  Now there are no spendable wallets.  The wallet - Trezor T no longer recognizes its password.  Therefore,  the Monero has vanished.  The Monero is either on the trezor T or in the Monero GUI Wallet both of which do not recognize the password.  This has become way more complicated than initially expected expected.  I should have kept the Monero on Exodus until this transferring of monero  has had a chance to be more accepted among and between applications.

Comment: Sorry, I missed User's comment.  I will look for that stack trace or similar, hopefully find it and post it.  -Thank You!

Comment: @Videomike - You can use this guide to recover your Trezor Monero wallet: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet/

Comment: I am so lost.  This is so frustrating.  Monero GUI on the MAC will not recognize my password.  WHY?  Why would it not recognize the password?  There are several wallets on the GUI that all have a balance of $0.00.  This is correct.  The Monero is in the Trezor T.  The Trezor T is a wallet.  A hardware wallet. It has its own 12 word ....phrase. So, I won't change that or make the Trezor T a new Hardware Wallet and lose all the coins inside it: giving it new words or password.  So how does one get the Monero out? Even seeing that it still exists would be nice.  Way too complicated!

Comment: So when I tried to make Monero Gui see the Trezor T,  I just get an error message that it cannot write files...  See the Log.  I have yet to find where the Log is.