# XMR wallet on Ledger X shows empty after restore, Why?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

My Ledger Nano X is working fine with my Monero wallet. But just as a matter of testing and making sure I can restore the wallet when something bad happens, I followed this guide to recover my wallet from my Ledger: [How do I restore / recreate my Ledger Monero wallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet)

I did not encounter any issues with that process, but for some reason the restored wallet seems completely empty. So, now I have two wallet files in my GUI on my PC, the restored-wallet is showing ZERO and the other is showing the correct amount.

First I thought I selected the wrong option and created a new wallet, tried a second time and made sure I selected the "Restore a wallet from device" option. With same result.

Both wallets have the exact same wallet-restore-height, primary-address, primary-view-key, primary-spend-key but with a different amount.
The network status is "Connected", Daemons and wallet are synced..
I also used the "Rescan wallet balance" option (which is done within a second.?!?), but with no results.

Any idea what I did wrong?

--- EDIT ---

After this post, I did another test on another PC with a complete new Unbuntu install. Installed the GUI and all, went through the recovery guide step by step (with advanced Node). Exact same results: the wallet appears to be empty.  So, now I have my old wallet on my laptop showing the correct amount of XMR, a recovered walled on my laptop showing 0, and the same now for my Desktop PC.

I recall that I did select the wrong option on my first attempt to recover the wallet. I had selected "Create a new wallet from device" instead of "Restore a wallet from device". Did that accidentally create some sort of shadow wallet on my Ledger?

Anyway, luckily I still had access to that old wallet on my laptop, so I was able to move the XMR to another software wallet. I then created a new wallet on my Ledger in "Account 1" (instead of the default "Account 0"), transferred the XMR to the new ledger-account-1 wallet, and was able to successfully recover that wallet on my desktop PC.

So, luckily in my case nothing was lost. But if I didn't had access to my old wallet then I would have lost my XMR...
I think it might be a bug that once you create a new wallet over your existing one, that you can't access the old anymore...

Anyone with a better idea of what went wrong?

Comment: This also happened to me. Didn't find fixes do far. Did you:

Comment: Sorry, I haven't. The main thing I learned after this, is that hardware wallet are nice, but I prefer paper wallets now as backup. And on a day-to-day basis run the software wallet in a Virtual-Box located on a VeraCrypt encrypted disk, or use Qubes as OS.