# If I reformat my MacBook that has MoneroGUI when i reinstall the wallet can i just create a new wallet from Ledger

Tags: ledger

My mac is messed up and I want to reformat the thing to help speed it up.  I have a MoneroGUI via Ledger Nano.  If I nuke my hard drive is my XMR gone?  Its keys are on the ledger so can I just not make a new wallet to view and manage XMR?

Comment: Do you have another Pc you can set up the MoneroGUI first? Since you have your keys backed up on ledger, all should be okay to proceed.

Comment: Hello.  No i do not.  It has to be on the same MacBook.  here is another question. can i install MoneroGUI on multiple operating systems using an identical private key from ledger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a MoneroGUI via Ledger Nano. If I nuke my hard drive is my XMR gone?

No. Your XMR is on the blockchain and your private key (the thing that enables you to *spend* the outputs you own that are on the blockchain), is on your Ledger device.

Both the GUI and `monero-wallet-cli` allow you to (re)create a wallet from a Ledger device. See this QA: [How do I restore / recreate my Ledger Monero wallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet)

Comment: Thank you for your answer jtgrassie