# Problem with Monero GUI and Ledger Nano S Plus

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

First I read this [guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui).

My system: Windows 10 (64)

A few months ago I created a Monero Wallet on the Ledger Nano S plus.
I transferred 1 Monero for test.
The Monero was displayed on the wallet.

A few days ago I wanted to restore my Monero Wallet on a new notebook with simple mode, but it appears only 0, no transactions are displayed.

I thought the 24 seed of ledger is enough to restore the wallet.

When I restore the wallet, which mode should I use, the simple or advanced mode?

Answer (score 0):

> but it appears only 0, no transactions are displayed

See: [I am missing (not seeing) a transaction to (in) the GUI (zero balance)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance)

> I thought the 24 seed of ledger is enough to restore the wallet.

See: [How do I restore / recreate my Ledger Monero wallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet)