# Lost password to GUI APP / do have passoword to my Ledger S / how to get: ACCOUNT ADDRESS + VIOW KEY + SPEND KEY?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

oh dear, when transferring my XMR I was so focused to have my password to my Ledger all safe. And somehow the seed phrase/height etc of the GUI APP completely passed me by!!

To get access to my wallet on the App, I am asked to enter:

- account address
- view key
- spend key

WHERE DO I FIND THOSE??
OR IS THERE ANY OTHER WAY TO GET ACCESS TO MY XMR ON MY LEDGER S?

So sorry asking this basic question.
As you can see I am not versed in these things at all :(

BIG THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!!

Agnes

Comment: If you use a Ledger Monero wallet, you can simply use the linked guide to recreate your wallet. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet/