# Nano Ledger S in GUI won't sync, blocks remaining keeps resetting

Tags: ledger

This is actually an issue someone is having on /r/MoneroSupport but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer. Here's the link directly to the post:

https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/ahhqjt/ledger_nano_s_and_gui_never_syncs_wallet_loop/

It seems the "wallet blocks remaining" gets near 0, then just pops back up all the way to the bottom of the blockchain and starts again. Does anyone know what causes this or how it's fixed?

Comment: Worth following [these steps](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/8504/7493) as a user guide.

Comment: Commented here -> https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/ahhqjt/ledger_nano_s_and_gui_never_syncs_wallet_loop/eefbmsn/