# Can't install Monero wallet, tried everything

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet

I can't install Monero wallet.

Error message is " error writing wallet from h/ware device,wrong device status"

I have tried everything. Latest version 17.1.4 . Monero app installed on my Ledger Nano x. Bypassed my anti virus.

Comment: Can you have a look at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-cli-monero-wallet-cli

Comment: I have tried going through command prompt or powershell as suggested,however the line "monero-wallet-cli.exe" is not recognized as a command or a file or anything.So i am stuck again.

Comment: Apologies, I linked the wrong guide. Here is the GUI guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui